# Is it possible to initialize a mock with when() inside a java stream

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-stream

I am writing a test where i have a set which will be put in to a method. I will then mock the method so it always returns return true.

I want to be able do this with help of a stream, so i can have a large Set. 
I am using JUnit4 for testing and Mockito for mocking.

Example:

```
setWithValues.stream().map(value-> when(method.returnTrueOrFalse(value)).thenReturn(true));
```

Comment: `Mockito.when(...).thenReturn?` I don't get it - this is exactly what a mock does. are you looking for something like `anyObject`?

Comment: I get the feeling that Johnboll wants to mock a method so that it returns true for all values defined in the set.

Comment: @Torben is correct. I want for each value in the set mock the return value. You can proberbly do this with a for each but i wonder if it is possible with a stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can only speculate what the problem is with the code, my guess is the mocking is never executed for the absence of a terminal operation, it feels just wrong. The thing is it introduces new stubbing for every value in your set. Consider following alternative:

```java
when(method.returnTrueOrFalse(Mockito.argThat(org.hamcrest.collection.IsIn.isIn(setWithValues)))).thenReturn(true);
// Or with static imports
when(method.returnTrueOrFalse(argThat(isIn(setWithValues)))).thenReturn(true);
```

It will aid debugability and will scale better with your set growing larger.

Comment: Yeah i am thinking the same that it never executes because of the lack of terminal operation. I like this solution it is clear what will happen, especially with imports. Thanks and well done Oliver!

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

(...)

Mockito.doAnswer(i -> setWithValues.contains(i.getArgument(0)))
    .when(method)
    .returnTrueOrFalse(ArgumentMatchers.any());
```